# How to fix invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class that includes a property that is itself a class.  I am trying to build a comparison operator for the parent class and I'm getting errors when writing the comparator code to check if the child property's attributes are equal.  The child itself compiles correctly.  The error I'm having trouble understanding is:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const struct wb_odometry' and 'const struct wb_odometry')
```

(And the *carrot* is located under the `==`.)

Why is there a problem if both sides are const and of the same type?  Would someone please help me fix it?

The error occurs in a class hierarchy as shown below which is designed to build as C or C++ code.  The `PROPERTY` macro defines getters and settors for the specified property type.

wb_odometry.h           (C)

```
struct wb_odometry
{
    PROPERTY(float, forward)
    PROPERTY(float, left)
    PROPERTY(float, turn)
};
```

==========================

wb_motion_status.h      (C)

```
#include "wb_odometry.h"

struct wb_motion_status
{
    PROPERTY(enum MotionState, motionState)
    PROPERTY(struct wb_odometry, motionOdometry)
    PROPERTY(bool, resetOdometry)
};
```

==========================

Odometry.h              (C++)

```
#include "wb_odometry.h"

class Odometry: public wb_odometry {

    inline bool operator== (const Odometry& a) const {
        return (fabs(static_cast<double>(forward() - a.forward())) < DBL_EPSILON &&
                fabs(static_cast<double>(left() - a.left())) < DBL_EPSILON &&
                fabs(static_cast<double>(turn() - a.turn())) < DBL_EPSILON);
    }
};
```

==========================

MotionStatus.h      (C++)

```
#include "wb_motion_status.h"
#include "Odometry.h"

class MotionStatus: public wb_motion_status {


    bool operator== (const MotionStatus &other) const {
        v==== ERROR NEXT LINE
        bool odometryEqual = motionOdometry() == other.motionOdometry();
        return motionState() == other.motionState() &&
               resetOdometry() == other.resetOdometry() &&
               odometryEqual;
    }
};
```

Comment: Provide a [mre]. We can't guess your code.

Comment: I've shown the relevant class hierarchy and the essential portions.  I'm sorry if you can't copy/paste it into a file and compile it.

Comment: Whats wb_odometry?

Comment: Yes, I realised my formatting skipped that class.  I've fixed that.

Comment: The whole point of struct is to group together data. Any good reason for using a struct as a class (though c++ permits this but that smells bad to me)

Comment: That lab where I'm a student does it this way as it allows us to build for C++ (with all the additional features) or as plain C with the essentials.  I've skipped the `#ifdef __cplusplus` etc.

Comment: My question is more about the meaning of the error message.  Once I understand that, I will be able to fix my code myself.

Comment: Do you have a link to a github page or something containing a Minimal Verifiable Complete Reproducible Example that gives this error?

Comment: @Hemil github links are not acceptable for a [mre].  All relevant code must be in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined an `operator==` for `class Odometry`, but not one for `struct wb_odometry`.  Since your equality test is between two `wb_odometry` objects, the compiler does not know how to compare them.

The easiest(?) fix would be to define a global `operator==` to compare two `wb_odometry` objects, which in this case would essentially be your `Odometry::operator==` but with two `const wb_odometry &` parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!!  But I took a slightly different approach in that I did this `bool odometryEqual = static_cast<Odometry>(motionOdometry()) == static_cast<Odometry>(other.motionOdometry());`.